# Jquery Validation WITHOUT Data Annotation in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, post

I want to create a page, in MVC, where there is a label, a textbox and a save link. Textbox will be initially in read mode and on double click of the textbox it is gonna come in edit mode. And when we fill textbox and click save link it gets saved in db. And for the text box, it should have various validations.
For these validations, I am planning not to use data annotations and work all with jquery or ajax. Also, I dont want to post the entire form, just the part where there is an edit.
Is this possible? If possible, then Please, can someone provide me some links or some help regarding this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: without server side validation you are just asking for a trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [JQuery Validation plug in](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation)..